# Pandas rank negative and positive integer, multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, math

I am not a mathematician, I'm a Finance guy and face a problem that is best to be described as follows:
I'm looking for advise on how to rank two series of integers, of which one has a domain in both positive and negative values and the other only has a positive domain.

High positive values of X are desired, high negative values are undesired.

Y is constrained to positives, high values are undesired, low values are desired.

My best guess so far has been:

In the positive domain this ratio makes sense: X/Y

In the negative domain (1/X*Y) tends to make sense, but I suspect it imposes an asymmetry.

Let's assume this is the ideal sorted series of X and Y

```
X, Y, rank
10,100, 6
10,1000, 5.5
1,100, 5.5
1,1000, 4
-1,100, 3
-1,1000, 2.5
-10,100, 2.5
-10,1000, 1
```

5.5 and 2.5 are numerically and conceptually similar (indifference).

Is there a function you could think of to use to rank and captures this logic?

A hard limit is that positive X is always better than negative X, therefore negative values of X should never be ranked higher than positive values of X.

Comment: so your expected rank for `10,100` the least ranked or the highest ranked in terms of value? 1 being the least(IMO)

Comment: 10,100 is the dominant choice, the best of all alternatives (highest rank).

Comment: Yes, i meant highest being the lowest rank in terms of numbers? if not my answer should suffice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I used [`series.rank()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) as below:*

```
df['new_rank']=df.X.rank(method='dense',ascending=True)+df.Y.rank(method='dense',ascending=False)-1
print(df)

    X     Y  rank  new_rank
0  10   100   6.0       5.0
1  10  1000   5.5       4.0
2   1   100   5.5       4.0
3   1  1000   4.0       3.0
4  -1   100   3.0       3.0
5  -1  1000   2.5       2.0
6 -10   100   2.5       2.0
7 -10  1000   1.0       1.0
```

Explanation in docs in the link provided.

Comment: With this solution negative values of X can be closely ranked to positive values of X, depending on Y. This is conceptually not what I'm after: Positive X dominates negative X, independent of Y. Any clues?

Comment: @Willem why not just go with X for ranking then? `df.X.rank(method='dense',ascending=True)` ??

Answer (score 1):

If you know the minimal value of your X serie, then the best is probably to use the following score :

```
(X + Xmin)/Y # Adding the minimal value as an offset is a standard procedure to obtain only positive values.
```

If you want to go further, you can even normalize both X and Y by performing :

```
X = (X + Xmin) / Xmax
Y = (Y + Ymin) / Ymax
```

and then perform score = X/Y

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption of using `X/Y`(if Y accepts 0 make sure you use X/1+Y) is correct. Now the matter is how much importance do you give  to X and Y????I mean, suppose `(aX)* (b*(1/y))` Now everything matters on `a` and `b`.

since importance of X increases as it's value increases, u may even use x^3 and punish higher negative terms and reward higher positive terms.

Coming to y, `1/(1+y^2)` if(y accepts 0, 1/0 is undefined so add 1 to it.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you still looking for a solution? I can post if it is still relevant. In short you first need to separate the problem a) split the metrics and b) calculate the scores. Ranking for ratios where metrics Hi to Low get bigger ranks for higher numbers (example Gross Profit margins, ROE, ROA). For this group you dont need to worry about negative numbers as they will get the appropriate weighting you would expect when sorted in descending order. The second group of ratios need to be batched into the Low to High category (such as Price to Earnings Ratio, Price to Book Value, etc) for this group you should pre-process them in a way that penalizes the negative numbers for this sub group. This requires changing the raw data so you should make a copy of the df for the pre-proccessing and ranking. I suggest using minmax scaling as the score as it only takes a small adjustment for this subgroup to be scored in the appropriate way using a sort on the minmax scaled ratios. Here is the partial solution to deal with preprocessing and scoring the metrics that are in the Low to High group. Note: if you really want to give a mean value to NaN values you add another lambda function either below or above the one I hae here which deals with negative values. A negative value here is added to the highest value so will get the lowest score. In my use of this for 49 financial ratios I leave the NaNs and just sum the scores. Otherwise a row or company could get a reasonable value even though most of the data is missing whereas with a sum of the scores it will still appear less attractive over all the ratios. `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def main():

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-14.00,90.20,np.nan,96.27,91.21],
                   'B':[103.02,-17.26,110.35,114.23,114.68], 
                   'C':['big','small','big','small','small']})
mycolumns=['A', 'B']
df_sub=pd.DataFrame(columns=mycolumns)      #used to protect the original data
for mycol in mycolumns:
    df_sub[mycol]=(df[mycol])
    cmax=df_sub[mycol].max()
    df_sub[mycol] = df_sub[mycol].apply(lambda x : x if x > 0 else (cmax-x))
    df[f'{mycol} Score'] = 1-(df_sub[mycol] - df_sub[mycol].min()) / (df_sub[mycol].max() - df_sub[mycol].min())
    print(f'Original Data with Scores:\n {df},\nScaled Data: \n {df_sub}')`
```

Comment: Please try to be specific as well as short at the same time. Do make use of proper text formatting.